# When can photon field amplitudes be written as field operators?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantization

Suppose I have some classical field equation for two photon fields with amplitudes $A_1(z),A_2(z)$ (plane waves) given as

${A}_1=\alpha f(A_1,A_2)  \\
  {{A}_2}=\beta g(A_1,A_2) $

Under what conditions can I make the replacement $A\rightarrow \hat{A}$ ? I am uncomfortable with the Bohr correspondence principle because the correspondence principle seems to be a very weak argument.

Edit: $z$ is position, $\alpha$,$\beta$ are real numbers. $f$ and $g$ are functions of the amplitudes.

Comment: If you're going to spend reputation on the bounty for this question, you might also want to spend some time cleaning up the question.  What is $z$?  What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  What are $f$ and $g$?  It's hard to tell what you're asking.